# Git revert changes

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout

I made a mistake moving between branches.

**git checkout -f myBranch**

This is my mistake and lost my data. is possible to revert or reset or rollback like undo to restore my files?

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Comment: not clear wht you are saying. you mean you lost uncommitted changes when you try to switch branches?? Normally when you have uncommited changes, git won't allow you try to switch branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out an other branch using `checkout -f`, your uncommited changes are lost (except for untracked files). As said [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) :

> -f
>   --force
>
> When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. **This is used to throw away local changes.**

If your changes were *local* and never even part of a commit, there is no way to restore them, since git does not know about them.

Any operation using `-f` or `--force` should be used with caution, since yout can potentially **loose your local changes** with no way to recover them. Make sure you have a clean working tree (e.g. commited local changes) before performing such operations.

I assume you lost your local changes here, or do you speak of changes that already were commited at any point?